# Intel App-Framework in UIWebView not showing navbar for iPhone 3.5" screen

Tags: ios, uiwebview, iphone-4, appframework

I found Intel's App-Framework to be light-weight and fast. However, I am facing a problem that I just can't seems to overcome. In the framework, one can display a navbar that 'stick' to the bottom of the screen. This work fine on the browser, WebView in Android and UIWebView in IOS - except on iPhone with 3.5" screen - the navbar just didn't show up. It appears that the screen is too short to show it.

I have tried playing with "viewport" meta tag by setting various 'height' and disabling & changing OS theme. Nothing works. Anyone has experience on this? How do I adjust the navbar position?

Comment: can you post your code or try one of these samples and check: https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates

Comment: Thanks for the templates; I'll give them a try and post my codes later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not the problem of App-Framework; it is the way UIWebView is placed on the view. After correctly setting UIWebView's top and bottom constraints, I am able to see the navbar correctly set at the bottom of the screen.